# Simple CSS Font Question

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` for content and I am using `<p>` and `<h4>` with nothing defined for either of them in my stylesheet. There is a big gap between the two. I'd like them to be flush on top of one another without the big gap. How do I do that ? CSS?

```
    <div id="content">

    <h4>Asdf</h4><br />
    <p>asdfjkl</p>

    </div>
```

THANKS!

Comment: You need to fix your format so we can see what you're referring to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CSS would be the way to do it.  If you want to do it just in one place you can put it inline like so:

```
<h4 style='padding-bottom:0px; margin-bottom:0px;'>Asdf</h4>
<p style='padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;'>asdfjkl</p>
```

You can do the same with the h4 to eliminate padding or margin.  If you want to put it into a separate CSS file:

```
h4 {
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
}

p {
 margin-top:0px;
 padding-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: It would be best to not use inline styles for this.

Comment: this did the job... why is it not "best"?

Comment: You usually want to separate the style (CSS), the content (HTML), and the behavior (JavaScript) from each other.

Comment: Ideally you would make a separate CSS stylesheet and put your changes in there.  Personally I think this is only relevant if you want this to apply to more than one page/situation.

Comment: Right, but is this deprecated syntax or would this not work in certain browsers?

Comment: It'll work. I like to separate it mainly to keep the code clean for when I go back and review it if I'm looking for mistakes.

Comment: In real markup I prefer to separate the styles into a stylesheet, but for Stack Overflow questions and answers like this one with snippets of markup I find inline styles easier to follow. Leave it to the reader to separate as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br />`. That is, change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="content"> 
  <h4>Asdf</h4>
  <p>asdfjkl</p> 
</div>
```

You can see this in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMMAW/).

Comment: @cssqst1 Er, if you look at the page I linked to with this HTML, there should be ne space between the `h4` and the `p`.

Comment: I just started a fresh html document and this is in it, and there is still the big gap:<html>


<body>

<h4>asdfasdf</h4>

<p>sadfad<p>
</body>

</html>

Comment: @cssqst1 I'm guessing the space is inherited from elsewhere in your CSS or perhaps it is a default in the browser you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag has a big margin. To edit the margin using CSS give the paragraph tag a class name, lets call it "margin", and then use CSS to edit the margins size using margin-top.

```
    <style type="text/css">
p.margin
{
margin-top:1px;
}
</style>
        <div id="content">

    <h4>Asdf</h4><br />
    <p class="margin">asdfjkl</p>

    </div>
```

Change the px to whatever you fancy.
The H tags also have big margins when you go higher in number, so I suggest you do the same trick for the h4, giving it the same class.

Answer (score 0):

If you still see the space, it may be because the `<h4>` or `<p>` is inheriting the spacing elsewhere. You can see for sure if you inspect the element. (How you do this depends on the browser you use, but a common way to do so in Firefox for example is by using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).)

To avoid this, give the `<p>` or `<h4>` tag a specific `class` (use class particularly if you will use it elsewhere on the page) and target the spacing by setting the margin/padding on the class. I show how below using `<p>` as the example.

In your HTML:

```
<div id="content"> 
  <h4>Asdf</h4>
  <p class="nospace">asdfjkl</p> 
</div>
```

In your CSS:

```
p.nospace {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

I'd try the above for both tags separately, and if you feel that both need that class you can do that by using the code below:

```
<div id="content"> 
  <h4 class="nospace">Asdf</h4>
  <p class="nospace">asdfjkl</p> 
</div>
```

In your CSS:

```
p.nospace, h4.nospace {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```